# jQuery Noob, list issues

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am a jQuery Noob and I am trying to get this list to work the way I'd like it to... `One li` is to be selected at a time and the others to be hidden. It works to the point that the `ul` expands to show the `li(s)` but then `doesn't allow you to select a different li`?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="search_buttons">
    <li class="1 selected_region">EUW</li>
    <li class="2 not_selected_region">EUNE</li>
    <li class="3 not_selected_region">NA</li>
    <li class="4 not_selected_region">LAN</li>
    <li class="5 not_selected_region">LAS</li>
    <li class="6 not_selected_region">BR</li>
    <li class="7 not_selected_region">TR</li>
    <li class="8 not_selected_region">RU</li>
    <li class="9 not_selected_region">OCE</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/K7cNxN8T) - shorthand:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "ul.search_buttons" ).click(function() {
      $( "ul.search_buttons li" ).each(function() {
        $( this ).toggleClass( "show_regions" );
      });
    });

    $( "ul.search_buttons li.1" ).click(function() {
      $( "ul.search_buttons li.1" ).each(function() {
        $( this ).addClass("selected_region");
            $("ul.search_buttons li.2").removeClass("selected_region");
                $("ul.search_buttons li.2").addClass("not_selected_region");

                ...
      });
    });
$( "ul.search_buttons li.2" ).click(function() {
  $( "ul.search_buttons li.2" ).each(function() {
    $( this ).addClass("selected_region");
        $("ul.search_buttons li.1").removeClass("selected_region");
            $("ul.search_buttons li.1").addClass("not_selected_region");

                ...
        });
    });

    ...
});
```

**CSS:**

```
li.nav_search:hover {background:none;}
ul.search_buttons {
margin:0;
padding:0;  
list-style-type:none;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
}
ul.search_buttons li {
padding:0;
padding-left:1%;
padding-right:1%;
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition:0.25s;
}
ul.search_buttons li:hover {cursor:pointer;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);}
li.show_regions {display:list-item !important;}
li.selected_region {display:list-item !important;}
li.not_selected_region {display:none;}
```

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/CMkhD/  Works for me

Comment: Just one explanation: you need 'default' region removed, and selected one on its place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need, in this case:

```
$( "ul.search_buttons" ).click(function() {
          $( "ul.search_buttons li" ).each(function() {
                $( this ).toggleClass( "show_regions" );
          });
        });

$( "ul.search_buttons li" ).click(function() {

          $( this ).addClass("selected_region");

    $( this ).siblings().addClass('not_selected_region');
      $( this ).siblings().removeClass('selected_region');


    });
```

Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/GFxb4/2/**  No need for countless lines. :)

Comment: Nice! thanks, I'm still learning jQuery.. I come from the land of PHP :D